# Spring + Quartz + JobStoreCMT

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I need help with quartz + jdbc Jobstore. 
Situation looks that:

I have spring application, and within this application there is quartz scheduler, it use persistence jobstore (JobStoreCMT with oracle Database). When i need to do some scheduled job, basicly I'm creating class with my annotation, where I'm writing for exapmle cron expression. When application starting, for all classes annotated like this are creating jobs, and scheduling with quartz.

When i don't want some job, i'm deleting his class, and there isn't loaded on startup. But what to do with already scheduled Job. When i'm starting my application without this Job Class, quartz want to recovery this job from Database JobStore, but this class is not exist, so i gets exeption.

Is there any  way to 'tell' quartz, that if job class doesn't exist, quartz should deleted it from scheduler ?

Answer (score 0):

There exists a `deleteJob()` method in the Scheduler class in order to delete Jobs. 
See http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/1.8.5/

You could also use `getJobNames()` to know if one of your jobs is missing.